# Simplifying a power series

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

$$\frac{n}{4}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k2^{1 - k} = n$$

More specifically I am curious how the below derivation is obtained. As in, why is the final result `n`.

[image]

Can someone please explain to me how the right-hand-side result is obtained?

Thanks.

Comment: @player3236 Fixed.

Comment: Welcom to MSE. Is $n$ have anything to do or you want to show only that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k2^{1 - k} = 4 \quad ?$$

Comment: @macton Posted the entire expression which I'm trying to understand.

Comment: yeah the $n$ is not important. In fact $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k2^{1 - k} = 4$$ is true. So are the any particular parts that you have confusions?

Comment: @macton I posted the entire expression. Am curious why from infinite series it goes to first derivative of the series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are considering the series
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^\infty kx^{k-1}
$$
which, is the (term by term) derivative of
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^\infty x^{k}
$$
since $\frac{d}{dx} x^k = kx^{k-1}$. It should be noted that this series converges only if $|x| < 1$.

Comment: That part is clear now.  Next, why is that part equal to $$\dfrac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1-x}$$?

Comment: is $$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty x^{k} = \frac{1}{1-x} \text{ for } x < 1$$ clear for you?

Comment: Only informally. (I looked at non-rigourous proof for that). Pretty sure why it converges for `x < 1`. The next terms becomes smaller and smaller meaning it converges for some number. Thanks a lot though, the entire expression makes a lot of sense now!

Comment: @CupOfGreenTea No problem, glad I can help you :)